# localhost:8080/style/style.css 404 Error

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I have seen many question like this but I have not seen the answer that works for my case so I have to post my own question.

I am using React, Node.js and Webpack on my project but front-end cannot find style/style.css file and gives me 404 error when the page is loaded.

My project folder structure looks like

```
├── root
│   ├── client
│   │   ├──src
│   │   │  ├──actions
│   │   │  ├──components
│   │   │  ├──reducers
│   │   │  ├──index.js
│   │   │
│   │   ├──style
│   │   │  ├──style.css
│   │   │
│   │   ├──index.html
│   │
│   ├──server
│      ├──server.js
│   
├── package.json
├── webpack.config.js
```

my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link 
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" 
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    >
    <script 
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" 
      integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" 
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    >     
    </script>
    <script 
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" i
      ntegrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" 
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    >  
    </script>
    <script 
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
      integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" 
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    >
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

and my webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './client/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./client/src/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/client',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

Seems that all components in `src` and even bootstrap are loaded fine but just `style/style.css` is not getting loaded to be styling my page.

If anyone can see what I'm doing wrong to load my `style/style.css` in webpage, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you,

Comment: Try to add the dot. `href="./style/style.css"`. And why are you using alpha of Bootstrap? There is beta 2 of it.

Comment: Actually just got it. I changed to `href="/client/style/style.css` and the error is gone. Thank you so much tho. Also, Thank you for the bootstrap advice, was just using what I found and will go ahead and change that too.

Comment: Although it might have fixed the error but it didn't fix the fundamental issue in your code. I suggest you to move this part of the code inside one of your js files as `import` since when you deploy your project to prod this hard coded link will be wrong and you gonna have to manually copy those files into their hard coded locations which is not a good idea.